# Requests depreciated warning on WordPress website

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings

I have a website which works on the latest version of WordPress (6.2 at the time of the writing). Recently my site started to throw a warning:

```
<br />
<b>Deprecated</b>:  The PSR-0 `Requests_...` class names in the Request library are deprecated. Switch to the PSR-4 `WpOrg\Requests\...` class names at your earliest convenience. in <b>/home/username/public_html/wp-includes/Requests/src/Autoload.php</b> on line <b>171</b><br />
```

The problem is: I have ajax requests which return this warning as well as an actual output breaking some pages. For now, I have opened the suggested `Autoload.php` file and just commented out `trigger_error` function call in this function:

```
public static function load($class_name) {
            // Check that the class starts with "Requests" (PSR-0) or "WpOrg\Requests" (PSR-4).
            $psr_4_prefix_pos = strpos($class_name, 'WpOrg\\Requests\\');

            if (stripos($class_name, 'Requests') !== 0 && $psr_4_prefix_pos !== 0) {
                return false;
            }

            $class_lower = strtolower($class_name);

            if ($class_lower === 'requests') {
                // Reference to the original PSR-0 Requests class.
                $file = dirname(__DIR__) . '/library/Requests.php';
            } elseif ($psr_4_prefix_pos === 0) {
                // PSR-4 classname.
                $file = __DIR__ . '/' . strtr(substr($class_name, 15), '\\', '/') . '.php';
            }

            if (isset($file) && file_exists($file)) {
                include $file;
                return true;
            }

            /*
             * Okay, so the class starts with "Requests", but we couldn't find the file.
             * If this is one of the deprecated/renamed PSR-0 classes being requested,
             * let's alias it to the new name and throw a deprecation notice.
             */
            if (isset(self::$deprecated_classes[$class_lower])) {
                /*
                 * Integrators who cannot yet upgrade to the PSR-4 class names can silence deprecations
                 * by defining a `REQUESTS_SILENCE_PSR0_DEPRECATIONS` constant and setting it to `true`.
                 * The constant needs to be defined before the first deprecated class is requested
                 * via this autoloader.
                 */
                if (!defined('REQUESTS_SILENCE_PSR0_DEPRECATIONS') || REQUESTS_SILENCE_PSR0_DEPRECATIONS !== true) {
                    // phpcs:ignore WordPress.PHP.DevelopmentFunctions.error_log_trigger_error
                    trigger_error(
                        'The PSR-0 `Requests_...` class names in the Request library are deprecated.'
                        . ' Switch to the PSR-4 `WpOrg\Requests\...` class names at your earliest convenience.',
                        E_USER_DEPRECATED
                    );
                    // Prevent the deprecation notice from being thrown twice.
                    if (!defined('REQUESTS_SILENCE_PSR0_DEPRECATIONS')) {
                        define('REQUESTS_SILENCE_PSR0_DEPRECATIONS', true);
                    }
                }

                // Create an alias and let the autoloader recursively kick in to load the PSR-4 class.
                return class_alias(self::$deprecated_classes[$class_lower], $class_name, true);
            }

            return false;
        }
```

But of course I understand that this solution is nothing but temporary and maybe someone knows how to fix the issue instead of just hiding it?

I have also printed out the `$class_name` variable and it turned out to be `Requests_IDNAEncoder`. I didn't use this class name in my code, so I assume it is used by something else, which is why I have no idea what do I need to change.

Comment: See what that comment there has to say? _"Integrators who cannot yet upgrade to the PSR-4 class names can silence deprecations by defining a `REQUESTS_SILENCE_PSR0_DEPRECATIONS` constant and setting it to `true`."_

Comment: The `\src` subdirectory under Requests is new with 6.2. There's probably a plugin or theme in play here.  And, [IDNAEncoder](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/requests_idnaencoder/) is related to handling internationalized hostnames with the [punycode spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3492).  Can you give us a traceback for the message you got? It might be a bug in newly-rolled-out 6.2. Or tell us how to reproduce this. Or just put `const REQUESTS_SILENCE_PSR0_DEPRECATIONS = true;` in your `wp-config.php` file and forget about the problem.

Comment: @O.Jones I would love to give you the full traceback, but this is all I got. It basically tells you about line 171, which is the `trigger_error` call. Let me know how to get the proper traceback and I will do that for you.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by changing the previous class name `Requests` to the new added namespace `WpOrg\Requests\Requests`

Sample with new namespace

```php
  //get countries
        $response  = \WpOrg\Requests\Requests::get(self::$enpoint . 'countries', [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . self::$skkey,
  ]);
```